# How to Replace Files?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, files

In current directory I have a file called `file.txt` with the contents:

```
new
```

and under the current directory there is a folder named `inner` with a file called `file.txt` with the contents:

```
old
```

How can I replace old `file.txt` with the new `file.txt` without asking for confirmation at all?

I tried:

```
mv -f file.txt ./inner
```

and inner directory was deleted!

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? OPen files and drag and drop.

Comment: @user68186 my point is to do this from command line

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Your `mv` tells the system to replace the file/directory called `./inner` as you didn't provide a directory to write into...  (ie. `./inner` and `.inner/` are very different things!)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I tried your command with and without `-f`. It worked both the time.

Comment: @guiverc sorry I didn't understand, so what should I write if I want to replace the file under `inner` directory?

Comment: plus what do you means by didn't provide a directory? the second argument for mv is the directory/destination.

Comment: `./inner/`  is a directory (the trailing / tells the shell you mean a directory), where as `./inner` is a file, ie. your `mv -f file.txt ./inner` is a command to rename `file.txt` as `inner` in the same directory; the `-f` tells the system to just do it & not ask for confirmation... ie. you're replacing any `./inner/` directory with a file that was previously named `file.txt`  (*sorry my prior comment was missing a character; `./inner` is what I intended to type*)  (do note you've tagged your `bash` interpreter as a really old & off-topic one!)

Comment: @guiverc thanks so I should do: `mv -f file.txt ./inner/`?

Comment: plus what you wrote contradicts: https://opensource.com/article/21/8/move-files-linux they didn't use `/` after `Documents`

Comment: Don't forget there are many shells available for Unix/Linux/POSIX, as well as different versions. You're using a *off-topic* (it's very *deprecated*) version, but also different GNU/Linux distributions can have different defaults (including different shells). I've explained what you saw, and it occurs on my non-14.04 system as I described (*excluding my typo errors; change settings & it doesn't occur on my system - but as you want it to do too*), but we maybe using different systems/versions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just move it or copy it. Example:

```
doug@s19:~/zzz$ cat file.txt
new
doug@s19:~/zzz$ cat inner/file.txt
old
doug@s19:~/zzz$ mv file.txt inner
doug@s19:~/zzz$ cat inner/file.txt
new
```

Comment: 1) is `mv file.txt ./inner` the same as: `mv file.txt inner`?   2) why didn't you use -f flag? as I said I don't want any warnings or questions to confirm before replacing old one

Comment: Yes, I could have done `mv file.txt ./inner` instead. I didn't use the -f flag because I didn't have to. There were no warnings or questions.